# QT C++ GUI app release does not play video

Tags: c++, windows, qt, user-interface

When I build a release version of my C++/QT app, the background animations don't play (all of type mp4). They do play, however, from within the Visual Studio debugger.

I have tried [the steps here](https://wiki.qt.io/Deploy_an_Application_on_Windows), and it still does not work when executed from the Deployment folder.

All DLLs, QML folders, and Plugin folders were copied over and still no luck.

I use the `windeployqt` technique to build.

I am building on Visual Studio 2017 and QT 5.12.2 (msvc2017)

```
windeployqt.exe --qmldir C:\Users\me\Documents\incommand2017\InCommand\Resources C:\Users\me\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release
```

I have included the Listdll result from when it works and when it doesn't:

Works:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
InCommand.exe pid: 848
Command line: "C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Debug\InCommand.exe" 

Base                Size      Path
0x0000000000d40000  0x6f1000  C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Debug\InCommand.exe
0x00000000e4ca0000  0x1f0000  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00000000e48f0000  0x55000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\wow64.dll
0x00000000e36f0000  0x7d000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\wow64win.dll
0x0000000077000000  0x9000    C:\WINDOWS\System32\wow64cpu.dll
0x0000000000d40000  0x6f1000  C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Debug\InCommand.exe
0x0000000077010000  0x19a000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
0x0000000074c60000  0xe0000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00000000765f0000  0x1fd000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\KERNELBASE.dll
0x0000000074800000  0x197000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\USER32.dll
0x0000000075330000  0x17000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\win32u.dll
0x0000000075b40000  0x21000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\GDI32.dll
0x0000000074fa0000  0x15a000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\gdi32full.dll
0x00000000752b0000  0x7c000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll
0x0000000076e80000  0x11f000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll
0x0000000074b10000  0xf7000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ole32.dll
0x0000000075870000  0x275000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\combase.dll
0x00000000763b0000  0xbb000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\RPCRT4.dll
0x00000000747e0000  0x20000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\SspiCli.dll
0x00000000747d0000  0xa000    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x0000000075350000  0x5f000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x0000000075140000  0x76000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
0x0000000076540000  0x79000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll
0x0000000076dc0000  0xbf000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll
0x000000007a260000  0xaa6000  C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Debug\Qt5Cored.dll
0x0000000075810000  0x5e000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WS2_32.dll
0x0000000075da0000  0x57a000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\SHELL32.dll
0x0000000076470000  0x3b000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll
0x0000000075b70000  0x84000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\shcore.dll
0x00000000767f0000  0x5c5000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\windows.storage.dll
0x0000000076320000  0x17000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\profapi.dll
0x0000000074c10000  0x43000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll
0x00000000753b0000  0xd000    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\UMPDC.dll
0x0000000076340000  0x44000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll
0x0000000075230000  0xf000    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll
0x0000000075100000  0x13000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\cryptsp.dll
0x000000007bba0000  0x181000  C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Debug\Qt5Multimediad.dll
0x0000000074e50000  0x92000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\OLEAUT32.dll
0x000000007bd30000  0x37000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Debug\Qt5MultimediaWidgetsd.dll
0x000000007bd70000  0x2cd000  C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Debug\Qt5Networkd.dll
0x0000000075c90000  0xfb000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\CRYPT32.dll
0x00000000751c0000  0xe000    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MSASN1.dll
0x000000007c040000  0x31000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Debug\Qt5SerialPortd.dll
0x00000000753c0000  0x449000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\SETUPAPI.dll
0x0000000075120000  0x19000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll
0x0000000073500000  0x18000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MPR.dll
0x0000000074210000  0x13000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\NETAPI32.dll
0x0000000074650000  0x1e000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\USERENV.dll
0x0000000074640000  0x8000    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\VERSION.dll
0x0000000074700000  0x24000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WINMM.dll
0x000000007c940000  0xb7000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MSVCP140D.dll
0x000000007ca00000  0x1b000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\VCRUNTIME140D.dll
0x000000007a0e0000  0x174000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll
0x00000000795b0000  0xb2c000  C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Debug\Qt5Guid.dll
0x000000007c080000  0x8be000  C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Debug\Qt5Quickd.dll
0x0000000071780000  0x91000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\DNSAPI.dll
0x0000000075d90000  0x7000    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\NSI.dll
0x00000000741d0000  0x32000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x0000000074680000  0x23000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WINMMBASE.dll
0x000000007ad10000  0x98000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Debug\Qt5OpenGLd.dll
0x0000000074100000  0xb000    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\NETUTILS.DLL
0x0000000078cd0000  0x8d5000  C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Debug\Qt5Widgetsd.dll
0x0000000071c40000  0x7a000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\UxTheme.dll
0x0000000071c10000  0x25000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll
0x00000000734e0000  0x1c000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\SRVCLI.DLL
0x000000007adb0000  0x839000  C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Debug\Qt5Qmld.dll
0x00000000765c0000  0x25000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\IMM32.DLL
0x000000007b5f0000  0xea000   C:\Qt\5.12.2\msvc2017\plugins\mediaservice\dsengined.dll
0x000000007b890000  0x84000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MF.dll
0x00000000565e0000  0x18e000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\d3d9.dll
0x000000006fd50000  0x19000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dxcore.dll
0x000000007b6e0000  0x90000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\EVR.dll
0x0000000001e60000  0x17d000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MFPlat.DLL
0x0000000001950000  0x1c000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dxva2.dll
0x0000000001990000  0x2a000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\RTWorkQ.DLL
0x0000000003630000  0x358000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MFCORE.DLL
0x0000000071490000  0x7000    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ksuser.dll
0x000000007b920000  0x106000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\mfperfhelper.dll
0x000000006db90000  0xbf000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\pmls.dll
0x00000000764b0000  0x6000    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\PSAPI.DLL
0x00000000731b0000  0x53000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\OLEACC.dll
0x0000000072940000  0x45c000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WININET.dll
0x0000000073410000  0x29000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll
0x00000000764c0000  0x80000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll
0x000000006a8b0000  0x76000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\Schannel.dll
0x0000000073600000  0x52000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\mswsock.dll
0x0000000003c10000  0x15000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devenum.dll
0x0000000072880000  0x23000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\DEVOBJ.dll
0x0000000075af0000  0x46000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WINTRUST.dll
0x000000006d710000  0x9000    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msdmo.dll
0x000000006b120000  0x62000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MMDevApi.dll
0x0000000051df0000  0x3a000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\wdmaud.drv
0x0000000071480000  0x8000    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\AVRT.dll
0x0000000077740000  0x11e000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\AUDIOSES.DLL
0x000000006b610000  0xda000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\wintypes.dll
0x0000000071470000  0xa000    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msacm32.drv
0x000000006d800000  0x19000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MSACM32.dll
0x000000006b110000  0x8000    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\midimap.dll
0x000000006d870000  0x7e000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dsound.dll
0x0000000004020000  0x199000  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\quartz.dll
0x0000000004540000  0x350000  C:\Qt\5.12.2\msvc2017\plugins\platforms\qwindowsd.dll
0x0000000074670000  0xf000    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WTSAPI32.dll
0x0000000004b00000  0x50000   C:\Qt\5.12.2\msvc2017\plugins\styles\qwindowsvistastyled.dll
0x0000000053590000  0x2e93000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\DriverStore\FileRepository\k127153.inf_amd64_3f3936d8dec668b8\igd9dxva32.dll
0x0000000074d40000  0x103000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MSCTF.dll
0x000000006a7b0000  0x31000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dataexchange.dll
0x000000006f750000  0x1de000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\d3d11.dll
0x0000000065730000  0x169000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dcomp.dll
0x000000006f9c0000  0xc1000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dxgi.dll
0x0000000062a30000  0x1e4000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\twinapi.appcore.dll
0x000000006a950000  0x1f000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\RMCLIENT.dll
0x0000000005070000  0x29000   C:\Qt\5.12.2\msvc2017\plugins\bearer\qgenericbearerd.dll
0x0000000071b20000  0x13000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x0000000071b00000  0x15000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x00000000050a0000  0x22000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Debug\bearer\qnativewifibearerd.dll
0x00000000050d0000  0xc9000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MSVCP120D.dll
0x00000000051a0000  0x1bf000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MSVCR120D.dll
0x0000000005360000  0x53000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\wlanapi.dll
0x00000000059d0000  0x8a000   C:\Program Files (x86)\K-Lite Codec Pack\Filters\LAV\LAVSplitter.ax
0x000000006e890000  0x20f000  C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.18362.657_none_2e72ec50278a619e\COMCTL32.dll
0x0000000005a70000  0x23c000  C:\Program Files (x86)\K-Lite Codec Pack\Filters\LAV\avutil-lav-56.dll
0x0000000005cb0000  0x49000   C:\Program Files (x86)\K-Lite Codec Pack\Filters\LAV\libbluray.dll
0x0000000005d00000  0x389000  C:\Program Files (x86)\K-Lite Codec Pack\Filters\LAV\avformat-lav-58.dll
0x0000000006090000  0x1350000  C:\Program Files (x86)\K-Lite Codec Pack\Filters\LAV\avcodec-lav-58.dll
0x00000000073f0000  0x2d000   C:\Program Files (x86)\K-Lite Codec Pack\Filters\LAV\avresample-lav-4.dll
0x000000006e3c0000  0x21000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ncrypt.dll
0x000000006d8f0000  0x28000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\NTASN1.dll
0x00000000730b0000  0x2f000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\rsaenh.dll
0x0000000056430000  0x1a3000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\DriverStore\FileRepository\k127153.inf_amd64_3f3936d8dec668b8\igdumdim32.dll
0x0000000063970000  0x19f2000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\DriverStore\FileRepository\k127153.inf_amd64_3f3936d8dec668b8\igc32.dll
0x000000000e4e0000  0x3fa000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ffdshow.ax
0x0000000074ef0000  0xb0000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\COMDLG32.dll
0x000000000dd40000  0x26000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\DINPUT.dll
0x000000000eb40000  0xff000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll
0x000000000e9e0000  0x3f000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\GLU32.dll
0x000000000ec40000  0xc2000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\inputhost.dll
0x00000000638e0000  0x89000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\CoreMessaging.dll
0x00000000627d0000  0x25e000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\CoreUIComponents.dll
0x00000000730e0000  0xc5000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\PROPSYS.dll
0x000000000ed10000  0xb79000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\DriverStore\FileRepository\k127153.inf_amd64_3f3936d8dec668b8\ig9icd32.dll
0x0000000012c10000  0x104000  C:\Program Files (x86)\K-Lite Codec Pack\Filters\LAV\LAVVideo.ax
0x0000000012290000  0x37000   C:\Program Files (x86)\K-Lite Codec Pack\Filters\LAV\avfilter-lav-7.dll
0x0000000012dc0000  0x94000   C:\Program Files (x86)\K-Lite Codec Pack\Filters\LAV\swscale-lav-5.dll
0x0000000013800000  0x1d2000  C:\Program Files (x86)\K-Lite Codec Pack\Filters\DirectVobSub\vsfilter.dll
0x0000000073220000  0x6b000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x0000000012f60000  0x13000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Debug\QtQuick.2\qtquick2plugind.dll
0x0000000012d20000  0x14000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Debug\QtQuick\Window.2\windowplugind.dll
0x0000000013ae0000  0x23a000  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msmpeg2vdec.dll
0x0000000012d40000  0x28000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CompPkgSup.DLL
0x0000000062610000  0x8b000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.StateRepositoryPS.dll
0x00000000131e0000  0xc6000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Debug\QtQuick\Controls.2\qtquickcontrols2plugind.dll
0x0000000013d20000  0x327000  C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Debug\Qt5QuickTemplates2d.dll
0x0000000012fc0000  0x7c000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Debug\Qt5QuickControls2d.dll
0x0000000013040000  0x44000   C:\Program Files (x86)\K-Lite Codec Pack\Filters\LAV\LAVAudio.ax
0x0000000013090000  0xc6000   C:\Qt\5.12.2\msvc2017\qml\QtQuick\Controls.2\qtquickcontrols2plugind.dll
0x0000000012ae0000  0xf000    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\resourcepolicyclient.dll
0x0000000015560000  0x96000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Debug\QtQuick\Templates.2\qtquicktemplates2plugind.dll
0x000000006bb90000  0x280000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dwrite.dll
0x000000001cfe0000  0x100000  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.UI.dll
0x0000000065980000  0x84000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\TextInputFramework.dll
0x000000001d240000  0x1a000   C:\Qt\5.12.2\msvc2017\plugins\imageformats\qgifd.dll
0x000000001d260000  0x1e000   C:\Qt\5.12.2\msvc2017\plugins\imageformats\qicnsd.dll
0x000000001d280000  0x19000   C:\Qt\5.12.2\msvc2017\plugins\imageformats\qicod.dll
0x000000001d2a0000  0xa9000   C:\Qt\5.12.2\msvc2017\plugins\imageformats\qjpegd.dll
0x000000001d350000  0x15000   C:\Qt\5.12.2\msvc2017\plugins\imageformats\qsvgd.dll
0x000000001d370000  0x91000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Debug\Qt5Svgd.dll
0x000000001d420000  0x16000   C:\Qt\5.12.2\msvc2017\plugins\imageformats\qtgad.dll
0x000000001d440000  0xa6000   C:\Qt\5.12.2\msvc2017\plugins\imageformats\qtiffd.dll
0x000000001d4f0000  0x15000   C:\Qt\5.12.2\msvc2017\plugins\imageformats\qwbmpd.dll
0x000000001d510000  0xed000   C:\Qt\5.12.2\msvc2017\plugins\imageformats\qwebpd.dll
0x000000007b780000  0x1b000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Debug\imageformats\qddsd.dll
0x000000007b7a0000  0xe9000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Debug\imageformats\qjp2d.dll
0x000000001d600000  0x7e000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Debug\imageformats\qmngd.dll
0x000000006f070000  0x229000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\iertutil.dll
0x000000006a700000  0x9f000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll
0x0000000023a70000  0x1c7000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\mfmp4srcsnk.dll
0x000000005c400000  0x61000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ntshrui.dll
0x0000000071390000  0xe000    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\cscapi.dll
0x000000006d550000  0x1ab000  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\urlmon.dll
0x000000005e530000  0x1b000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\edputil.dll
0x000000005e510000  0x1b000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\CLDAPI.dll
0x0000000062520000  0x8000    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\FLTLIB.DLL
0x00000000626d0000  0x11000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\napinsp.dll
0x00000000626b0000  0x16000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\pnrpnsp.dll
0x00000000626a0000  0xb000    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\winrnr.dll
0x0000000061e20000  0x16000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\NLAapi.dll
0x000000005e570000  0x10000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\wshbth.dll
0x0000000074110000  0xbd000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\winhttp.dll
0x0000000071450000  0x8000    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rasadhlp.dll
0x0000000071320000  0x51000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\fwpuclnt.dll
```

Not Working:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
InCommand.exe pid: 10072
Command line: "C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\InCommand.exe" 

Base                Size      Path
0x00000000001b0000  0x392000  C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\InCommand.exe
0x00000000e4ca0000  0x1f0000  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00000000e48f0000  0x55000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\wow64.dll
0x00000000e36f0000  0x7d000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\wow64win.dll
0x0000000077000000  0x9000    C:\WINDOWS\System32\wow64cpu.dll
0x00000000001b0000  0x392000  C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\InCommand.exe
0x0000000077010000  0x19a000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
0x0000000074c60000  0xe0000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00000000765f0000  0x1fd000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\KERNELBASE.dll
0x0000000074800000  0x197000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\USER32.dll
0x0000000075330000  0x17000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\win32u.dll
0x0000000075b40000  0x21000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\GDI32.dll
0x0000000074fa0000  0x15a000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\gdi32full.dll
0x00000000752b0000  0x7c000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll
0x0000000076e80000  0x11f000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll
0x0000000074b10000  0xf7000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ole32.dll
0x0000000075870000  0x275000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\combase.dll
0x00000000763b0000  0xbb000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\RPCRT4.dll
0x00000000747e0000  0x20000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\SspiCli.dll
0x00000000747d0000  0xa000    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x0000000075350000  0x5f000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x0000000075140000  0x76000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
0x0000000076540000  0x79000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll
0x0000000076dc0000  0xbf000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll
0x0000000074e50000  0x92000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\OLEAUT32.dll
0x0000000075da0000  0x57a000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\SHELL32.dll
0x0000000076470000  0x3b000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll
0x0000000075b70000  0x84000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\shcore.dll
0x00000000767f0000  0x5c5000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\windows.storage.dll
0x0000000076320000  0x17000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\profapi.dll
0x0000000074c10000  0x43000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll
0x00000000753b0000  0xd000    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\UMPDC.dll
0x0000000076340000  0x44000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll
0x0000000075230000  0xf000    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll
0x0000000075100000  0x13000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\cryptsp.dll
0x000000007c500000  0x19000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\Qt5MultimediaWidgets.dll
0x000000007ba60000  0x90000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\Qt5Multimedia.dll
0x000000007c830000  0x103000  C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\Qt5Network.dll
0x0000000075c90000  0xfb000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\CRYPT32.dll
0x00000000751c0000  0xe000    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MSASN1.dll
0x0000000075810000  0x5e000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WS2_32.dll
0x000000007c010000  0x4e3000  C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\Qt5Core.dll
0x000000007c520000  0x310000  C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\Qt5Quick.dll
0x000000007baf0000  0x51f000  C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\Qt5Gui.dll
0x000000006fc20000  0x13000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\VCRUNTIME140.dll
0x000000007c940000  0x14000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\Qt5SerialPort.dll
0x00000000753c0000  0x449000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\SETUPAPI.dll
0x0000000075120000  0x19000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll
0x0000000071780000  0x91000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\DNSAPI.dll
0x0000000075d90000  0x7000    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\NSI.dll
0x00000000741d0000  0x32000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x000000006fc40000  0x6f000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MSVCP140.dll
0x0000000073500000  0x18000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MPR.dll
0x0000000074210000  0x13000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\NETAPI32.dll
0x0000000074650000  0x1e000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\USERENV.dll
0x0000000074640000  0x8000    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\VERSION.dll
0x0000000079130000  0x45000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\Qt5OpenGL.dll
0x000000007c960000  0x24000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\WINMM.dll
0x0000000078cd0000  0x457000  C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\Qt5Widgets.dll
0x0000000074680000  0x23000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WINMMBASE.dll
0x0000000071c40000  0x7a000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\UxTheme.dll
0x0000000071c10000  0x25000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll
0x0000000079180000  0x1c000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\SRVCLI.DLL
0x000000006d730000  0xb000    C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\NETUTILS.DLL
0x00000000791a0000  0x347000  C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\Qt5Qml.dll
0x00000000765c0000  0x25000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\IMM32.DLL
0x0000000079860000  0x12c000  C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\platforms\qwindows.dll
0x000000006d710000  0xf000    C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\WTSAPI32.dll
0x000000006db90000  0xbf000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\pmls.dll
0x00000000764b0000  0x6000    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\PSAPI.DLL
0x00000000731b0000  0x53000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\OLEACC.dll
0x0000000072940000  0x45c000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WININET.dll
0x0000000073410000  0x29000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll
0x000000006a8b0000  0x76000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\Schannel.dll
0x0000000073600000  0x52000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\mswsock.dll
0x00000000794f0000  0x23000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\styles\qwindowsvistastyle.dll
0x00000000565e0000  0x18e000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\d3d9.dll
0x000000006fd50000  0x19000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dxcore.dll
0x0000000053590000  0x2e93000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\DriverStore\FileRepository\k127153.inf_amd64_3f3936d8dec668b8\igd9dxva32.dll
0x0000000074d40000  0x103000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MSCTF.dll
0x00000000764c0000  0x80000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll
0x000000006a7b0000  0x31000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dataexchange.dll
0x000000006f750000  0x1de000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\d3d11.dll
0x0000000065730000  0x169000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dcomp.dll
0x000000006f9c0000  0xc1000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dxgi.dll
0x0000000062a30000  0x1e4000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\twinapi.appcore.dll
0x000000006a950000  0x1f000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\RMCLIENT.dll
0x0000000079520000  0xe000    C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\bearer\qgenericbearer.dll
0x0000000071b20000  0x13000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x0000000071b00000  0x15000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x00000000795a0000  0xff000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\opengl32.dll
0x0000000079530000  0x3f000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\GLU32.dll
0x00000000038f0000  0xb79000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\DriverStore\FileRepository\k127153.inf_amd64_3f3936d8dec668b8\ig9icd32.dll
0x0000000063970000  0x19f2000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\DriverStore\FileRepository\k127153.inf_amd64_3f3936d8dec668b8\igc32.dll
0x00000000730e0000  0xc5000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\PROPSYS.dll
0x0000000079a60000  0x9000    C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\QtQuick.2\qtquick2plugin.dll
0x0000000079a70000  0x9000    C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\QtQuick\Window.2\windowplugin.dll
0x0000000079a80000  0x74000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\QtQuick\Controls.2\qtquickcontrols2plugin.dll
0x0000000079b00000  0x26000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\Qt5QuickControls2.dll
0x0000000079b30000  0xd3000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\Qt5QuickTemplates2.dll
0x0000000079c10000  0x44000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\QtQuick\Templates.2\qtquicktemplates2plugin.dll
0x000000006bb90000  0x280000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dwrite.dll
0x0000000079570000  0xb000    C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\imageformats\qgif.dll
0x0000000079580000  0xd000    C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\imageformats\qicns.dll
0x0000000079590000  0xb000    C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\imageformats\qico.dll
0x00000000796a0000  0x5d000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\imageformats\qjpeg.dll
0x0000000079700000  0xa000    C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\imageformats\qsvg.dll
0x0000000079a10000  0x44000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\Qt5Svg.dll
0x0000000079710000  0x9000    C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\imageformats\qtga.dll
0x0000000079720000  0x55000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\imageformats\qtiff.dll
0x0000000079780000  0x9000    C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\imageformats\qwbmp.dll
0x0000000079790000  0x6d000   C:\Users\aidan.oshea\Documents\incommand2017\Win32\Release\imageformats\qwebp.dll
0x0000000065980000  0x84000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\TextInputFramework.dll
0x00000000627d0000  0x25e000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\CoreUIComponents.dll
0x00000000638e0000  0x89000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\CoreMessaging.dll
0x000000006b610000  0xda000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\wintypes.dll
0x000000006f070000  0x229000  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\iertutil.dll
0x00000000626d0000  0x11000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\napinsp.dll
0x00000000626b0000  0x16000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\pnrpnsp.dll
0x00000000626a0000  0xb000    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\winrnr.dll
0x0000000061e20000  0x16000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\NLAapi.dll
0x000000005e570000  0x10000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\wshbth.dll
0x0000000074110000  0xbd000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\winhttp.dll
0x0000000071450000  0x8000    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rasadhlp.dll
0x0000000071320000  0x51000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\fwpuclnt.dll
```

I've even tried taking all the DLLs listed when it works and bringing them into the release folder.

Has anyone been down this road before?

Comment: please provide all relevant information (a [mre]) in the question itelf without links to third party sites (which look like they will expire in a few days)

Comment: Since you know how to reproduce the issue, why don't you go ahead and debug it?

Comment: @IInspectable And how would I go about that?

Comment: Launch your process and attach a debugger.